# How to prove that a problem is NP complete?

Tags: algorithm

I have problem with scheduling. I need to prove that the problem is NP complete. What can be the methods to prove it NP complete?

Comment: Read "Reducibility Among Combinatorial Problems" by Karp.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

To show a problem is NP complete, you need to:

### Show it is in NP

In other words, given some information `C`, you can create a polynomial time algorithm `V` that will verify for every possible input `X` whether `X` is in your domain or not.

#### Example

Prove that the *problem of vertex covers* (that is, for some graph `G`, *does it have a vertex cover set of size `k` such that every edge in `G` has at least one vertex in the cover set*?) is in NP:

- our input `X` is some graph `G` and some number `k` (this is from the problem definition)
- Take our information `C` to be "any possible subset of vertices in graph `G` of size `k`"
- Then we can write an algorithm `V` that, given `G`, `k` and `C`, will return whether that set of vertices is a vertex cover for `G` or not, in **polynomial time**.

Then for every graph `G`, if there exists some "possible subset of vertices in `G` of size `k`" which is a vertex cover, then `G` is in `NP`.

**Note** that we do **not** need to find `C` in polynomial time. If we could, the problem would be in `P.

**Note** that algorithm `V` should work for **every** `G`, for some `C`. For every input there should **exist** information that could help us verify whether the input is in the problem domain or not. That is, there should not be an input where the information doesn't exist.

### Prove it is NP Hard

This involves getting a known NP-complete problem like [SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem), the set of boolean expressions in the form:

> (A or B or C) and (D or E or F) and ...

where the expression is *satisfiable*, that is there exists some setting for these booleans, which makes the expression *true*.

Then **reduce the NP-complete problem to your problem in polynomial time**.

That is, given some input `X` for `SAT` (or whatever NP-complete problem you are using), create some input `Y` for your problem, such that `X` is in SAT if and only if `Y` is in your problem. The function `f : X -> Y` must run in **polynomial time**.

In the example above, the input `Y` would be the graph `G` and the size of the vertex cover `k`.

For a *full proof*, you'd have to prove both:

- that `X` is in `SAT` => `Y` in your problem
- and `Y` in your problem => `X` in `SAT`.

**marcog's** answer has a link with several other NP-complete problems you could reduce to your problem.

Footnote: In step 2 (**Prove it is NP-hard**), reducing another NP-hard (not necessarily NP-complete) problem to the current problem will do, since NP-complete problems are a subset of NP-hard problems (that are also in NP).

Comment: I wonder if there is missing data or a circular reasoning behind this. I mean how to 'prove' a problem is in NP *without referring it to other problem* that 'is already in NP'? It's like say "it's made of iron because its part are known to be iron", that's not an iron proof.

Comment: As far as I remember, there is a theorem called the Cook-Levin theorem which states that SAT is NP-complete. That proof is quite a bit more complicated than what I outlined above and I don't think I can explain it in my own words.

Comment: To be more precise, the Cook-Levin Theorem states that SAT is NP-complete: any problem in NP can be reduced in polynomial time by a deterministic Turing machine to the problem of determining whether a Boolean formula is satisfiable (SAT). So that's the missing piece you were asking about. If you look up the theorem on Wikipedia there is a proof, and you can reference the theorem in your proof. 
That said, reducing SAT to a given problem is the way I was taught to prove NP-completeness.

Comment: So my question ends up being if SAT could be solved in polynomial i.e. the P = NP problem.. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Could you please explain why we can't reduce a NP-hard problem to the problem we want, in the second step? Does it has to be a NP-complete problem?

Comment: @MLT You can definitely reduce a NP-hard problem to the problem you want to prove. You can take a look at this note (Page 6), hope it helps. http://web.engr.illinois.edu/~jeffe/teaching/algorithms/notes/30-nphard.pdf

Answer (score 25):

You need to reduce an NP-Complete problem to the problem you have. If the reduction can be done in polynomial time then you have proven that your problem is NP-complete, if the problem is already in NP, because:

It is not easier than the NP-complete problem, since it can be reduced to it in polynomial time which makes the problem NP-Hard.

See the end of http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960312.html for more.

Comment: +1 someone who explains understandably. instead of saying a bunch of references to keywords I hardly understand.

Comment: The first sentence is back-to-front: you need to reduce the known NP-complete problem *to* your own problem.  This shows that your problem is *at least as hard as* the known NP-complete problem.  Part (b) is also incorrect: if you have found the reduction then you already know that your problem is NP-hard; the only question is whether it is in NP at all (some problems, like the Halting Problem, are not).  Iff it is NP-hard and in NP, then it is NP-complete (i.e. "NP-complete" is more specific than "NP-hard").

Comment: I wouldn't say a) leads to a contradiction, since we don't know that P != NP.

Answer (score 18):

In order to prove that a problem L is NP-complete, we need to do the following steps:

1. Prove your problem L belongs to NP (that is that given a solution you can verify it in polynomial time)
2. Select a known NP-complete problem L'
3. Describe an algorithm f that transforms L' into L
4. Prove that your algorithm is correct (formally: x ∈ L' if and only if f(x) ∈ L )
5. Prove that algo f runs in polynomial time

Answer (score 8):

First, you show that it lies in NP at all.

Then you find another problem that you already know is NP complete and show how you polynomially reduce NP Hard problem to your problem.

Comment: No. You need to show that you can reduce from an NP complete problem to your NP problem to prove NP completeness AND prove it is in NP at all. NP hard doesn't come into this, unless you can't prove its in NP.

Answer (score 7):

1. Get familiar to a subset of NP Complete problems
2. Prove NP Hardness : Reduce an arbitrary instance of an NP complete problem to an instance of your problem. This is the biggest piece of a pie and where the familiarity with NP Complete problems pays. The reduction will be more or less difficult depending on the NP Complete problem you choose.
3. Prove that your problem is in NP : design an algorithm which can verify in polynomial time whether an instance is a solution.